# Reset selected file input in JQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to write a jQuery method to delete the selected file to clear it out? How can I pass the file name to jQuery to reset the file input?

I don't want to clear all the files at once.

Here are my files:

```
<div class="field fieldTEXT">
    <form:label path="file" cssClass="fieldLabel">
    Attach Competitor: 
    </form:label>

    <form:input path="file" type="file" cssClass="fileInput" accept="application/pdf"/> <a href="" onclick="RemoveFile();" > Remove</a>
</div>
        <div class="field fieldTEXT">
            <form:label path="file2" cssClass="fieldLabel">
                Attach 2
            </form:label>
            <form:input path="file2" type="file" cssClass="fileInput"/> <a href="" onclick="RemoveFile();" > Remove</a>

        </div>
        <div class="field fieldTEXT">
            <form:label path="file3" cssClass="fieldLabel">
                Attach Additional Information:
            </form:label>
            <form:input path="file3" type="file" cssClass="fileInput" accept="application/pdf"/> <a href="" onclick="RemoveFile();" > Remove</a>    
        </div>
        <div class="field fieldTEXT">
            <form:label path="file4" cssClass="fieldLabel">
                Attach Additional Information (If Needed):
            </form:label>
                <form:input path="file4" type="file" cssClass="fileInput" accept="application/pdf" /> <a href="" onclick="RemoveFile();" > Remove</a>

        </div>
```

In my JS:
How can I pass the name to my JS file and reset the selected link?

```
function RemoveFile(name) {
    $('input[type=file]').val('');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works, please ignore the changes I made to the html, that is for generating the HTML in the editor.

**Explanation:** If you add an event handler to all the `a` tags in the form with classes `field fieldTEXT` the function will get called, the event will provide us a `this` which is basically the clicked element. Then using the jquery function `prev()`, I access the element before the `a` tag, which is the `input` element, then we clear the field using `val('')`

```js
$('.field.fieldTEXT a').on('click', function(){
     $(this).prev().val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field fieldTEXT">
            <form:label path="file2" cssClass="fieldLabel">
                Attach 2
            </form:label>
            <input path="file2" type="file" cssClass="fileInput"/> <a href="#"> Remove</a>

        </div>
        <div class="field fieldTEXT">
            <form:label path="file3" cssClass="fieldLabel">
                Attach Additional Information:
            </form:label>
            <input path="file3" type="file" cssClass="fileInput" accept="application/pdf"/> <a href="#"> Remove</a>    
        </div>
        <div class="field fieldTEXT">
            <form:label path="file4" cssClass="fieldLabel">
                Attach Additional Information (If Needed):
            </form:label>
                <input path="file4" type="file" cssClass="fileInput" accept="application/pdf" /> <a href="#" > Remove</a>

        </div>
```

Comment: any good explanation on why it doesn't work for the first click on Remove link :/ .. it will work after the first click :D

Comment: @Samarland as you can see the code works, I would suggest you do `$('.field.fieldTEXT a').on('click', function(){
     console.log($(this).prev());
     $(this).prev().val('');
});` and check the previous element, if its the input tag. Form elements are not generated in the text editor, so I couldn't use the exact code.

Comment: It will work for the same Remove link for the second click, and will work for the first click on any other input

Comment: @Samarland if you could replicate the issue in a jsfiddle will help you solve this

Comment: @Samarland if you could replicate the issue in a jsfiddle I will check it for you

Comment: @Samarland Sorry I could not fix it fully, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

Get all the elements and check each object if they have file. and clear if file is exist

```
$('input[type=file]').each(function(i, obj) {
    if(obj.files.length){
        obj.val('');
     }
});
```